# How to make the debugging in playframework in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: debugging, playframework

Here we have a link

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0.1/ide

about how to configure playframework to be working with different IDEs. There they say a couple of words about debugging, but it is not clear - how can I perform the debugging? If I put a break-point, let's say in my Model's constructor class, then how and what I should launch to initialize debugging? I use IntelliJ Idea.

For example when I use Jboss, or Tomcat, there is an option in the IDE within those servers to run them in debug mode or "normal" mode. But how to work with Play Framework in this context? Should I configure remote debugging somehow?

Comment: For those using Play 2, this tutorial was very helpful: http://digitalsanctum.com/2012/05/26/play-framework-2-tutorial-debugging-with-intellij-idea/

Comment: Follow up for play 2 at http://stackoverflow.com/q/24218341/873282

Answer (score 10, accepted):

when you launch Play Framework (via **play run**) you will see that is says that the debug port is running at a certain address. This is a standard Java behavior on servers (having a debug port enabled).

Most IDEs allow you to set up a connection to that remote port so you can debug the code remotely. The specific steps will depend on the IDE you are using, but it should be as simple as that.

Answer (score 41):

Most convenient way to run/debug applications in intellij IDEA is the following.

Menu command: Run -> Edit Configuration!

[image: Edit configuration]

Add new configuration -> Application

Then fill up the fields:

*Main class:*

**play.server.Server**

*VM Parameters:*

**-Dapplication.path=.**

You should have something similar:

[image: configuration screen]

If you did it correctly, then you can run and stop your app right from IDE

**EDIT for Play! 2**

Play 2 has good documentation for debugging. So go read it. But if you want to investigate run/debug buttons method - read further.

It is different for Play 2.

**Settings:**

*Main class:*

**play.core.server.NettyServer**
or
**play.core.server.ProdServerStart**

*VM Parameters:*

**-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9999
-Dapplication.path=.**

You still can debug your application by pressing debug button but I have not figured out some issues:

- It always starts in PROD mode, so you can't make hot code changes.
- RUNNING_PID. There is an error when you restart your debugging session saying that you have to delete this file.

Comment: but this is just for running and stopping but not for debugging, right?

Comment: And let's add a quite important thing, `-Dplay.id=yop` to specify the play framework id.

Comment: append for VM parameters -Dplay.id=test, and add in module settings in dependencies add Single-Entry Module Library, choose $PLAY_HOME/modules/testrunner/lib/play-testrunner.jar

Comment: This method does not work with Open JDK.  You must use the Sun JDK.  I'm not sure why.  But magically things worked when I switched from the Open JDK 6 to Sun JDK 6.

Comment: FYI, For Play 2, after I did `play debug`, I tried `play start` and even though the debugger managed to attach, my breakpoints weren't hit. I tried `play run` and that worked better for me.

Comment: When trying the Play! 2 instructions I got "NettyServer.main is deprecated. Please start your Play server with the ${ProdServerStart.getClass.getName}.main." (I'm running this project: http://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/play-scala-intro)

Comment: replacing "play.core.server.NettyServer" by "play.core.server.ProdServerStart" worked in my case

Comment: life saver. Thanks :)

Answer (score 21):

If its a play project, from the command line :

```
play debug
```

If its a SBT play project from the command line :

```
 sbt -jvm-debug 9999 run
```

debug port is 9999 by default

now create a remote configuration

in IntelliJ :

Go to "edit run configurations"

[image]

Create a new remote configuration (port 9999, all other details leave with default values)

[image]

run the new debug configuration (don't forget to put a break point)

Answer (score 17):

In Play 2, simply do the following:

- From the shell, run `play debug`
- You'll be dropped into the debug console. Type `run` and hit enter.
- Then create a Remote configuration in IntelliJ IDEA set up for "localhost" and 9999.
- Start the new configuration

Comment: Here is a more verbose version of these steps: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/IDE

Comment: Every reference I can find in play website is using `sbt`. Where this application `play` (`play debug`) come from? How can I install this?

Comment: @CarlosCaldas I don't think it exists anymore. Play no uses vanilla `sbt` now. I'm not up to date on Play these days, so I'm not sure what the new way is to start debugging.

Answer (score 10):

I had to change this line in my build.sbt from:

fork in run := true

to

fork in run := false

for the breakpoints to work in IntelliJ IDEA 15.0 with the Play 2 App run configuration.

Comment: This worked for me, when running (well, debugging) as SBT Task.

Comment: Debugger would connect but not hit any breakpoints until changing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem.

play (cloned from github at 2011-08-28) and intellij 10.5

SEVERE: Cannot read application.conf

my fix was: -Dapplication.path=. (without "")

to set -Djavaagent=... was no longer necessary on my box.

Comment: That was it for me too.  On Mac OSX

Answer (score 5):

Since version 11 of IDEA, there is native support for the Play framework in the ultimate edition. 
To debug your Play application do the following:

- from the command-line, create a new demo app using 'play new demoapp'
- from the command-line, create Intellij project/module files using 'play idea demoapp'
- optionally edit .iml file and change '1.6' by '1.7' if you use the latest JDK (bug!)
- start Intellij, and open the demoapp project
- Go to Run/Edit Configuration
- Press the '+' button, and add a 'remote' configuration
- Choose Transport:socket, Debugger mode:Attach, Host:localhost, Port 8000
- Set the 'name' and the 'classpath-module'
- Start the Play! framework support in IDEA by choosing Tools/Play framework
- Start the demo application by typing 'play run play101' in the Play! console
- Set a breakpoint in the Application.java file on the 'render()' line
- Start the 'remote' debug configuration.
- In a browser, go to http://localhost:9000

You should now hit the breakpoint.

Comment: This is almost right, but you have to do "play debug" not "play run"

Comment: @Gertjan ... you are absolutely right. I could not save my updated answer due to the localhost URL, so i hope people read these comments.

Comment: I used play 1.2.5 and it does not have `play debug` command. However, Jan's method, and just set module = no module (IDEA IntelliJ 11), and it works.

Answer (score 2):

With an SBT project, you can debug from the IDE debugger with an *SBT Task* configuration (Run->Edit Configurations-> Add New Configuration->SBT Task) - with the *Tasks* setting set to:

*"run 9000" "-jvm-debug 9999"*

9000 is the site port, 9999 is the default debug port. The quotes are required

Then select the configuration & debug

Works with the community edition (2016.2)

Answer (score 0):

my fix was:
open the "Run/Debug Configurations" dialog, then change the "working directory" to the project directory.

Answer (score 0):

I just executed the application, on dev mode, on port 8080. Play automatically opens port 8000 for JVM debug.

Then create a new Run/Debug configuration with the template "Remote JVM Debug" and set the port to 8080.

Answer (score 0):

Run -> Edit configurations
Run/Debug Configurations => Remote JVM Debug

You change only port to 9999 and leave everything as it is (default values)
[Run/Debug Configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EZuc.png)

Then in IntelliJ Terminal button menus next to build(console, by default the path to root directory of the project) and run

```
sbt -jvm-debug 9999 run
```

Then debug in this buttom menu then click on the Rerun 'RemoteJVMDebygName' or
Run (next to file) Debug 'RemoteJVMDebygName'

Before you should have tried

```
sbt compile

sbt run
```

sbt -jvm-debug 9999 run =>
[image: sbt -jvm-debug 9999 run]

One you click on run -> debug 'XXX' or the green bug in the Debug
[image]

If you hit a break point at http://localhost:9000/
[image]