# playframework tests in intellij idea

Tags: unit-testing, playframework

I've read this:
http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/1df0a77ef811a225

but not found the answer in fact

i have turned on the

```
module.testruner=${play.path}/modules/testrunner
```

in my application.conf

but still have the errors when try to launch some test form the ide (idea), following error:

```
May 7, 2011 9:56:31 PM play.Logger fatal
SEVERE: Cannot read application.conf
```

question: how to launch the tests from idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In play 1.2 you don't need additional setup to run tests in intelliJ test runner. Just check to make sure that you've configured your run/debug configuration correctly. Look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390178/how-to-make-the-debugging-in-playframework-in-itellij-idea/5390609#5390609).

Comment: yes. i should make this settings for every test then. or for whole test-set i'm going to run.