# Running playframework tests as a IntelliJ IDEA JUnit run configuration

Tags: junit, intellij-idea, playframework

I've been trying to run the unit tests in a play application from IntelliJ directly from the built in test runner. (To get the nice UI, click through etc.)

This works for very basic FunctionalTest tests and when it starts it gives the following logging:

```
16:18:08,353 INFO  ~ Starting /home/sindrit/projects/testapp/.
16:18:08,370 INFO  ~ Module crud is available (/home/sindrit/play-1.2.3/modules/crud)
16:18:08,949 WARN  ~ You're running Play! in DEV mode
16:18:10,242 INFO  ~ Connected to jdbc:h2:mem:play;MODE=MYSQL;LOCK_MODE=0
16:18:11,033 INFO  ~ Application 'testapp' is now started !
```

Indicating play is actually starting.

However more complicated tests using database access fail with exceptions like this:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Please annotate your JPA model with @javax.persistence.Entity annotation.
at play.db.jpa.GenericModel.count(GenericModel.java:232)
at model.BeanTest.testCreate(BeanTest.java:16)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at play.test.PlayJUnitRunner$StartPlay$1$1$1.execute(PlayJUnitRunner.java:73)
at play.Invoker$Invocation.run(Invoker.java:265)
at play.Invoker.invokeInThread(Invoker.java:67)
at play.test.PlayJUnitRunner$StartPlay$1$1.evaluate(PlayJUnitRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at play.test.PlayJUnitRunner.run(PlayJUnitRunner.java:48)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:94)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:192)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:64)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:115)
```

I expect this is because the instrumentation is not working as it does when running play. The same test runs fine in `play auto-test`.

Through some google searches I've found that I should need at lest the following parameters:

- -javaagent:/home/sindrit/play-1.2.3/framework/play-1.2.3.jar
- -Dfile.encoding=utf-8
- -Dplay.debug=yes
- -Dplay.id=test
- -Dapplication.path=/home/sindrit/projects/testapp

Has anyone here gotten this to work?

What JVM parameters or classpath or other things do I need to make the IntelliJ test runner emulate the play runtime environment?

If I add play-testrunner.jar to the dependencies I get the following error:

```
play.exceptions.CompilationException: The type BasicTest is already defined
at play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler$2.acceptResult(ApplicationCompiler.java:246)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.handleInternalException(Compiler.java:672)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:516)
at play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler.compile(ApplicationCompiler.java:278)
at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.getAllClasses(ApplicationClassloader.java:412)
at play.Play.start(Play.java:485)
at play.test.PlayJUnitRunner.<init>(PlayJUnitRunner.java:31)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:31)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:93)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:79)
at com.intellij.junit4.IdeaSuite.<init>(IdeaSuite.java:37)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit46ClassesRequestBuilder.getClassesRequest(JUnit46ClassesRequestBuilder.java:34)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4TestRunnerUtil.buildRequest(JUnit4TestRunnerUtil.java:81)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:61)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:192)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:64)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:115)
```

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this? I have to spin up the play webserver or use play auto-test when I just really want to run one test now.

Comment: No, and this remains unresolved. As far as I can tell play does some magic to the JVM that I don't know how to replicate in IntelliJ test runner (maybe it's not possible at all).

Answer (score 0):

I maybe over simplifying this but it seems you may have forgotten the Entity annotation on your database models.

Your models should look like this.

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "pkg_load" )
public class PkgLoad extends Model {

}
```

Or this if you don't want to use the built in ID in model.

```
    @Entity
@Table( name = "pkg_load" )
public class PkgLoad extends GenericModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    @Basic( optional = false )
    @Column( name = "pkg_load_id" )
    public Long pkgLoadId;
}
```

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/jpa

The Entity annotation is found in the `javax.persistence` library.

Comment: To repeat what I said in the question, the tests run successfully when run with the play command on command line. This exception only comes up when running the test from within IntelliJ JUnit run config.

Comment: I misread  your post.  I thought you said that you have gotten tests to run in Intelli J but when you try to do a more advanced test using database it fails.  I didn't think you meant you got the same exact test to run.  It's obvious that it's failing on the model class though.  Java stack traces are straight forward.

Comment: I speculated in my question that it might be that some sort of instrumentation that happens when running play doesn't happen when I run in IntelliJ. The question is really: "What JVM parameters or classpath or other things do I need to make the IntelliJ test runner emulate play?".

Comment: I just don't think that's the problem.  I just set up IntelliJ on Mac with built in test runner and didn't have any problems.  Can you post some of your code?

http://www.jamesward.com/2011/07/28/setup-play-framework-with-scala-in-intellij

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390178/how-to-make-the-debugging-in-playframework-in-itellij-idea/5390609#5390609

Comment: Based on the thread you linked to I added play-testrunner.jar to the project dependencies. Now I get an error from the compiler for all tests, I'll update the question with that stack trace.