# Debugging SBT project with Play in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

I have a SBT project

in this project i have a sub play project and other projects

example from my build file :

```
 lazy val subProj1 = Project(id = "sub-proj-1", base = file("sub1"))
.settings(...)...

 lazy val subProjPlay =  play.Project("play-proj", 1.0 , path = file("web"))
```

need to debug the play server from IntelliJ IDEA.

To run the project I use `sbt run` on the command line.

How can I debug the project in IDEA?

Answer (score 34):

I found this to be the easiest solution : (using IntelliJ IDEA )

in IntelliJ :

Go to "edit run configurations"

[image]

Create a new remote configuration (port 9999, all other details leave with default values)

[image]

Go back to IntelliJ and run the new debug configuration (don't forget to put a break point)

From command line run :

```
 sbt -jvm-debug 9999 run
```

Comment: The best about this is you can use it for any app that runs on jvm. E.g. maven build, tests, remote application server ...

Answer (score 12):

The easiest solution.

1. Edit Configurations... -> add `SBT Task` (not `Remote` task).
   Specify SBT Task: `~run`.
2. Run created `SBT Task` using - [image: Debug] Debug button

Comment: FYI, if this doesn't work as is, you must edit your build.sbt file `fork in run := true` to `fork in run := false`

See markus answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390178/how-to-make-the-debugging-in-playframework-in-intellij-idea

Comment: Works for me. I didn't have to edit my build.sbt file (it actually doesn't have a `fork in run` entry.

Answer (score 2):

Provided you've Play distribution installed locally, use `play debug run` on the command line and connect to `localhost` on the port `9999` in IDEA.

From [Debugging section in Using the Play console](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/PlayConsole) in the official Play 2.2.x documentation:

> You can ask Play to start a JPDA debug port when starting the console.
>   You can then connect using Java debugger. Use the play debug command
>   to do that

If however you don't have it (and for a reason don't want to install it), add `Remote` Run configuration in IDEA that will give you a hint for the command line arguments you should be using when launching SBT, e.g.

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
```

When you launch SBT that may or may not be as simple as launching SBT jar, just use the above to configure JVM to run in debug mode.

Comment: i dont have play installed on my machine so i cant run command play
this is a sbt project

Comment: Doh, I thought since it's a Play project you use play distro installed locally. Sorry. I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1 && Play Framework 2.5.3

For me, no matter how I set(create new Run/Debug Configuration for Play 2 App or SBT Task, specify the debug port, execute in Run or Debug mode) in the IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1 Enterprise Edtion, the IDEA can not open the debug port(default 9999), so the debug is impossible.

After disable the sbt-fork-run-plugin(comment it in /project/paly-fork-run.sbt), it works!!!

I am newer to Play framework,and have found many bugs...Compare to RoR, it's so hard to learn, to run, to use, to debug...

Below is my steps:

1. disable the sbt-fork-run-plugin(comment it in /project/paly-fork-run.sbt)
2. execute `activator -jvm-debug 9999 "run 11111"` (I use port 9999 to debug, port 11111 to run my Play project)
3. In IDEA, add an new Run/Debug configuration, Choose, set debug port to 9999
4. debug the new created configutation

Comment: disabling sbt-fork-run-plugin was a key here! Thanks a lot