# How to run Play Framework 2.x in debug mode in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.0, typesafe-activator

I want to run Play Framework 2.x in debug mode in IntelliJ IDEA. I searched in the Internet and all results say that you have to use play console.

Is it possible to run in debug mode in IntelliJ IDEA without using play console?

Comment: You can find your answer in the last. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24218341/how-to-run-play-framework-2-x-in-debug-mode-in-intellij-idea/35869872#35869872

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use Idea 12+ *Ultimate Edition*

- Install *Play 2.0 Support*, *Scala* and other required plugins in Idea
- In command line perform `play idea` to generate project
- Open created project in Idea (**open**, don't import)
- Go to: *Menu* > *Run* > *Edit Configurations...* > *Add New Configuration...* > choose *Play 2 App*
- In *Menu* > *Run* new buttons will appear *Debug* and *Run*, first will run app with enabled debbuger.

Comment: Why is `play idea` required since IDEA supports play/sbt projects?

Comment: How does it work with Idea 16. In version 14 I had done the same, but I cant find Play in the debug config.

Answer (score 30):

Using activator :

1. From Terminal (Not intellij terminal), enter command : *activator ui*
2. Open your existing app
3. Choose "Code view & Open in IDE
4. In Browse Code, click setting icon
5. Choose Open Project in Intellij IDEA
6. Generate
7. Open Intellij IDEA
8. Open project - browse your app directory
9. Run - Edit Configuration
10. Add new configuration - Remote
11. *Add* name
     *Setting*
     transport : socket, debugger mode : attach, Host : localhost, port : 9999
     module clashpath : your app
12. Tools - Open Terminal
13. *activator -jvm-debug 9999 run*
14. Run debug
15. Open browser localhost:9000

Comment: Small error on step-11, the port should be '9999' if you start the jvm debugger with port '9999'

Comment: In Play 2.5 at least, I also had to edit build.sbt and make sure it had 'fork in run := false'

Comment: same, can't get this to work also have fork in run set to false. I'm sure i'm doing something wrong but 3 hours on SO haven't turned up anything.

Answer (score 5):

Preparation: Do not use the project creation by activator ui or similar. Just
open the project in IntelliJ.

1. `activator -jvm-debug 9999 ~run`. The `~` before `run` enables automatic reloading of generated HTML pages
2. In IntelliJ:

   1. Run > Edit Configurations...
   2. Select Defaults/Remote
   3. Click on the green + at the upper left corner
   4. Give the name "Play 2"
   5. Ensure that Transport:Socket and Debugger mode:Attach are selected
   6. Type in `9999` as port
      [image: Preferences Screenshot]
   7. Press "OK"
3. Run > Debug Play 2 (second entry in the list)

Pro hint: Check out the [play-auto-refresh](https://github.com/jamesward/play-auto-refresh) plugin to have Chrome automatically reloading on a change.

(based on @ARM's answer)

Comment: Just wow. Didnt expected to have debugging running in 2min. This man deserves an cookie!

Answer (score 4):

1. Open Intellij IDEA
2. Open project - browse your app directory Run - Edit Configuration
3. Add new configuration - Play2
4. Add **http://localhost:9000** to url to open option
5. Add **-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M** to JVM option
6. Set Debug port to  9999
7. Set your debug point and debug your application.   Cheers :)

**FYI** : All of the above fields might filled up already

[image]

Comment: what does ```-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled``` do?

Comment: I removed above CMSClassUnloadingEnabled which was automatically added and were creating errors with it; removing it did not appear to have further problems.

Answer (score 3):

this works for me and maybe easier

1. file menue => settings => Build, Execution, Deployment => sbt => check "Enable debugging for sbt shell"
2. idea sbt shell now will start with debug enable, log out the port as "Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 52701"
3. Run/Debug Configurations => Add(the pluss(+) sign) => Remote => Set "Port" And "Use module classpath"
4. just type run in sbt shell, then click debug button

screent shot

1. enable idea emaded sbt debug
   [image]
2. sbt shell start log
   [image]
3. add remote in "Run/Debug"
   [image]
4. type run here
   [image]