# Doesn't work debug for play project in IDEA 14 Ultimate

Tags: scala, debugging, intellij-idea, playframework, breakpoints

I do following steps:

1. Import to IDEA Play project generated with Activator UI from Play Scala Seed template.
2. Create Run/Debug configuragion using standart "Play 2 App" template.
3. Add break point in my project.
4. Run debug and open page in a browser.
5. I can see in IDE console "play - Application started", and debugger tells me
   "Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:58354', transport: 'socket'"

But program execution doesn't stop at my break points. In a browser I can see 
what a code for that I've made a break point is executed. 
What's wrong with IDEA?

I use play version 2.3.9, and I start the play app from an IDEA ide not from a play console.

Comment: Do you start `Play` from console or from `Intellij`?

Comment: Which version of play do you use?

Comment: I use play version 2.3.9, and I start the play app from an IDEA ide not from a play console.

Comment: Silly question, but are you sure your code is going through the breakpoints?

Comment: Yes, I'm completely sure. It's very simple app like that:  `object Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
  }
}` I put break point on Line `Ok(views....)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems duplicate with :

[How to run Play Framework 2.x in debug mode in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24218341/how-to-run-play-framework-2-x-in-debug-mode-in-intellij-idea)

Your first step seems wrong. Just open (and don't import) your project is enough from IntelliJ.