# Java Play - How run Play in IntelliJ with custom sbt configurations options

Tags: java, intellij-idea, build, playframework, sbt

#### The problem

I need to run a Play2 Java application build with sbt using IntelliJ Ultimate.
When using the option 'Run Play 2 App` it works but it runs with default configuration.

How can I supply custom sbt configuration in IntelliJ?

#### More in Details

I can run in the terminal and it works with this command

```
sbt  -J-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions "start -Dconfig.file=/conf/application.conf -Dpidfile.path=/dev/null -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dlogger.file=/conf/logback.xml"
```

Now, in the `application.conf` there are many custom configuration but the most noticable is the Play web port which is `play.server.http.port=5000`
So I can see straigh away that it picked up the correct configuration at the start.

```
--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] p.c.s.NettyServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

Server started, use Alt+D to stop
```

Now in IntelliJ there is a build in 'Play 2 App' *Run/Debug configurations* but really I don't see any way to:

1. Supply sbt arguments
2. Run sbt with command 'start' but instead it runs always as `sbt run' (I know this because the` sbt start` is in production mode and the application need to run in that way at the moment

[image]

I also try with run/debug as 'Application' following this old answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5390609/13903942

I **almost** works. I can give the stb option but I can't choose to run as `sbt run` or `sbt start` it seems it always run as `sbt start`

Ultimatelly I need any other run/debug option.

I don't need **running from terminal solution**, this I know how to do it.
THe whole point to pay a Ultimate version of Intellij is to be able to run and Run the debugger with the IDE (otherwise I ll use something else)

Is there a way?

Honestly, is probably one of the worst un-documented and twisted situation I've being facing in relation to the fact that, we are talking about Java is very known programming language, Play framework stand basically at top position on Java frameworks and well IntelliJ integration,  I'm astonish on how bad is and the amount of hours I'm spending just to make this run.

Comment: what's the message showed when you start the app from intellij? once you hit run or debug, it shows the full command executed. I guess the port where you want to start the app is related with the `Url To Open` field

Comment: I am not at pc right now, ill tey tomorrow and let you know the output. Yes i didnt try to change 'url to open'. Now if that fixes the port (and i guess host) i would be very surprise on how bad the UI and unclear is . Anyways still the question is also on how to add the path for config (and any other options) what jt seems to be at first glancd is that, is a feature they didnt developed and left it pretty basic

Comment: I think the field `JVM Options` is the right place for passing parameters to the jvm. When you try to execute the app, the first line showed in the console should be the command that intellij used to start it. The params should be listed there.

Comment: @GastónSchabas thanks it worked! Honestly, I did try to set the config insive the JVM but i didnt notice that it worked becuase the port thing throw me off. Actually (without going in details) certain thing had to work at that specific port and didn't happened. The port is actually defined in the .conf file. So few things happened:  1. IMO define the 'port'    of the app on a input box called `Url To Open` is very very weird. and is really agains the Principle of least astonishment https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment, one can say this is a perfect example of it.

Comment: @GastónSchabas 2. That means that, it OVERRIDES silently the configuration file I provide . Eitheway this stuff happens in this industry .. thanks for the help and to provide also some code sample ;)

Comment: The play run configuration from intellij starts the play app in development mode. You can [set the port using the sbt console](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/PlayConsole#Using-the-play-commands-directly) with the command `sbt "run <http port>"`. When you build the app and start it in production mode, you can [override the port and other properties](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ProductionConfiguration#Specifying-the-HTTP-server-address-and-port-using-system-properties).

Comment: Here you have a link about how you can [use Play in production](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/Production)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some time and I was able to validate what I said in the comments.

- port can be set changing the value of `Url To Open`
- params for the JVM can be set changing the value of `JVM Options`

---

I just created a play java project using the [play-java-seed](https://github.com/playframework/play-java-seed.g8) template with the sbt command

```scala
sbt new playframework/play-java-seed.g8
```

Refactored the `HelloController` to log some messages before return the 200 Ok response

```java
import com.typesafe.config.Config;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import play.mvc.*;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class HomeController extends Controller {

    // started the logger
    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass().getCanonicalName());

    final Config config;

    // injected the config
    @Inject
    public HomeController(Config config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    public Result index() {
        // logged some messages using different log levels
        logger.debug("A super debug message");
        logger.info("An info message");
        logger.warn("A warning message");
        // logged a message using a value provided in the config file
        logger.info("the value of some-key is " + config.getString("some-key"));
        return ok(views.html.index.render());
    }

}
```

I created two run configurations in Intellij:

##### prod

- `Url To Open`

```
http://localhost:9020
```

- `JVM Options`:

```java
-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
```

- set the log level root to `INFO` and added the prefix `PROD STDOUT -`  for the log messages in `logback.xml` file
- added the line `some-key = "A Prod Value"` to `application.conf` file

[image: run web app prod]

Got the following output

```bash
/<path to java home>/bin/java 
  -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 
  -Djline.terminal=none 
  -Dsbt.global.base=/private/var/folders/n3/7h5c5s2x1d1f_m_vz22h73280000gn/T/sbt-global-pluginstub 
  -Dsbt.log.noformat=true 
  -Xms512M 
  -Xmx1024M 
  -Xss1M
  -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Didea.managed=true 
  -classpath "<intellij app path>/IntelliJIdea2023.1/plugins/Scala/launcher/sbt-launch.jar" xsbt.boot.Boot "project root" "run 9020" # new value for the port

#############################################
some init log messages from play
#############################################

# next you can see the prefix added
PROD STDOUT - 2023-08-05 18:23:10 INFO  play.api.Play  Application started (Dev) (no global state)
PROD STDOUT - 2023-08-05 18:23:11 INFO  controllers.HomeController  An info message
PROD STDOUT - 2023-08-05 18:23:11 WARN  controllers.HomeController  A warning message
PROD STDOUT - 2023-08-05 18:23:11 INFO  controllers.HomeController  the value of some-key is A Prod Value
# above you can see the value of the key from the config file
```

##### dev

- `Url To Open`

```java
http://localhost:9010
```

- `JVM Options`: set path for config and logback files, replaced the values for `Xms`, `Xmx`  and `Xss`

```java
-Xmx2048M -Xss2M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Dconfig.file=conf/dev-application.conf -Dlogger.file=conf/dev-logback.xml
```

- set the log level root to `DEBUG` and added the prefix `DEV STDOUT -`  for the log messages in `dev-logback.xml` file
- added the line `some-key = "A Dev Value"` to `dev-application.conf` file

[image: run web app dev]

Got the following output

```
/<java home path>/bin/java 
  -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 
  -Djline.terminal=none 
  -Dsbt.global.base=/private/var/folders/n3/7h5c5s2x1d1f_m_vz22h73280000gn/T/sbt-global-pluginstub 
  -Dsbt.log.noformat=true 
  -Xms1024M # param edited 
  -Xmx2048M # param edited
  -Xss2M    # param edited
  -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled 
  -Dconfig.file=conf/dev-application.conf # param added
  -Dlogger.file=conf/dev-logback.xml      # param added
  -Didea.managed=true 
  -classpath "/<intellij path>/IntelliJIdea2023.1/plugins/Scala/launcher/sbt-launch.jar" xsbt.boot.Boot "project root" "run 9010" # here you can see the value of the port I set in `Url To Open`

#############################################
some init log messages from play
#############################################

# next you can see the prefix added for dev and also the log level is set ot DEBUG
DEV STDOUT - 2023-08-05 18:34:18 DEBUG controllers.HomeController  A super debug message
DEV STDOUT - 2023-08-05 18:34:18 INFO  controllers.HomeController  An info message
DEV STDOUT - 2023-08-05 18:34:18 WARN  controllers.HomeController  A warning message
DEV STDOUT - 2023-08-05 18:34:18 INFO  controllers.HomeController  the value of some-key is A Dev Value
# above you can see the value of the key from the config file
```

Comment: This is also valid for a scala play app